# Bitnami Meanstack Mongoose Connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose, bitnami

I created a simple service in Ubuntu 16.04 with mongo db node and express to return data to an angular 2 app.

I have a file called server.js that connects to a local mongodb instance with a database called game and a collection called players. It works fine installed on my local machine. However I am trying to deploy it with Bitnami's mean stack image on amazon ec2. (bleh mouth full). I have set ports correctly according to [this guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-2), and I can connect to it remotely. However, I can't get mongoose to connect to any database. here is my code that works on my local machine.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/game');

router.route('/player')



.get(function(req, res) {
    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
    Player.find({"player":user,"password":password},function(err, Test) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(Test);
    });
});
```

And here is my adjusted code for the mean stack image

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:"My-Root-Password@127.0.0.1:27017/game');
 router.route('/player')
.get(function(req, res) {

console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
    Player.find({"player":user,"password":password},function(err, Test) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(Test);
    });
});
```

On my local machine I get a value of 1 on the console.log and value of zero on the mean stack image. I'm not sure how to connect to bitnami's mongo instance with mongoose. I have checked that game exist and has the data I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix Although I don't yet fully understand it. It came from the guide I posted [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-a-mean-app-to-amazon-ec2-part-2) . First I had to un comment out the section of the mongodb.conf that says `noauth = true` then comment out the line that says `auth = true`. I then restart mongo, and create a new user with permissions to read and write the the data base I want to use like this

```
db.createUser({
    user: "NEW USERNAME",
    pwd: "NEW PASSWORD",
    roles:[
            {
                    "role" : "readWrite",
                    "db": "game"
            }
    ]})
```

After creating the user I undo what I did to `noauth = true` and `auth = true`, and restart mongodb. Then I am able to connect with mongoose like this

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://NEW USERNAME:NEW PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:27017/game');
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB 3.0, they added a new authentication mechanism for MongoDB (more details in the links below).

Authentication information: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/

How to use the new authentication mechanism: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/improved-password-based-authentication-mongodb-30-scram-explained-part-2

Due to this, the guide provides that workaround to get the connection with the database. Now, you have created that user with "readWrite" privileges on your database so you are able to use it.